# Passing NamedTemporaryFile to a subprocess on windows

Tags: python, temporary-files

The [python docs for `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) say:

> Whether the name can be used to open the file a second time, while the named temporary file is still open, varies across platforms (it can be so used on Unix; it cannot on Windows NT or later).

I have a program that's invoked as `prog input.txt`, that I can't touch. I want to write a python function to give this a string.

Here's various approaches that don't quite work:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
```

1. Not obvious if legal on windows

   ```
   with NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
       f.write(contents)
       subprocess.check_call(['prog', f.name])  # legal on windows?
   ```
2. Might delete the file too early

   ```
   with NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
       f.write(contents)
       f.close()  # does this delete the file?
       subprocess.check_call(['prog', f.name])
   ```
3. Doesn't clean up properly

   ```
   with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
       f.write(contents)  # if this fails, we never clean up!
   try:
       subprocess.check_call(['prog', f.name])
   finally:
       os.unlink(f.name)
   ```
4. A little ugly

   ```
   f = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
   try:
       with f:
           f.write(contents)
       subprocess.check_call(['prog', f.name])
   finally:
       os.unlink(f.name)
   ```

Which of these are correct?

Comment: Did you ever find out the solution to this question?

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, the first three variants are all broken - the first one will throw a `PermissionError` on Windows; the second one does indeed delete the file too early; and the third one doesn't handle exceptions properly.

Your fourth snippet is therefore the correct way to do it.

---

However, as you said, it is a little ugly. I suggest wrapping it in a function to improve readability and reusability:

```
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

@contextmanager
def ClosedNamedTempfile(contents, mode='w'):
    f = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, mode=mode)
    try:
        with f:
            f.write(contents)
        yield f.name
    finally:
        os.unlink(f.name)
```

Which allows us to use it like so:

```
with ClosedNamedTempfile('foobar\n') as f:
    subprocess.check_call(['prog', f])
```

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. The subprocess trying to access 'f' still reports that the file doesn't exist inside the `check_call` environment.